# Are there performance comparison between Java sort and Scala sort?

Tags: java, scala

Scala has scala.util.Sorting for sorting and Java also has sort method on collection. Are there any performance comparison between these two languages as far as sorting goes?

Comment: why don't you benchmark it yourself?

Comment: Because a single benchmark on a person's computer tells undoubtedly that one is faster then the other.

Comment: Why not look at the source? At least for java I know you can and the Arrays.sort() method uses mergeSort, which is O(n log n).

Comment: I'm not sure, but as far as I'm concerned Java does the quick sort and Scala does the merge sort. But as I said, I'm not sure. If I'm right, then of course there are differences...

Comment: @Nicholas: java is doing an insertion sort for small arrays and a "tuned quicksort" for the rest, not merge sort.

Comment: @tulskiy: You're right. I was only checking a for Objects. They used a variety of sort methods depending on what the array is, but for and array of Objects it's using MergeSort.

Comment: @Nicholas: right, sorry, I didn't check the rest of sort methods.

Comment: @tulskiy: We both made each others mistake. But yeah, pretty much java tried to use the best sorting algorithm out there for the given solution.

Answer (score 2):

Documentation for the Sortingobject says that

> These implementations are derived from those in the Sun JDK.

so I guess it is same quicksort and there should be no difference.

benchmark it yourself with small (less than 10 elements) and large (about 1 Mb of data) collections.